# Puppet having trouble accessing the value of hash in hiera data

Tags: puppet, hiera

This is my global.yaml file

```
---
puppet:
  running: 'running'
  atboot: true
```

When I run "hiera --config hiera.yaml puppet" the output is

```
{"running"=>"running", "atboot"=>true}
```

Which is the expected output.

But when I try to access the inner values by running "hiera --config hiera.yaml puppet::running" I get nil value.
My hiera version is 3.0.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding that `puppet::running` is a key name, whereas you seem to want `puppet.running`.

If you have a common.yaml file with:

```
---
puppet:
  running: running
  atboot: true

puppet::running: foo
```

In the latest Puppet 5 and 6, you could try this (remembering that the hiera CLI command is deprecated in favour of puppet lookup):

```
$ puppet lookup puppet
---
running: running
atboot: true

$ puppet lookup puppet::running
--- foo

$ puppet lookup puppet.running
--- running
```

Or, in your version of Puppet:

```
$ hiera puppet
{"running"=>"running", "atboot"=>true}

$ hiera puppet::running
foo

$ hiera puppet.running
running
```